# Laravel - Sending email with Logo in body

Tags: laravel, image, email

I want to send an email attaching the logo in the email body. I am using Laravel. But whenever I am trying to attach an image, it is not showing in the body. Instead, it is sending as an attachment. Any suggestion or article link would be helpful for me

**The result i am getting**
[image]

**Sample**

[image]

**Mailable**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SubscribeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Test Mail')->view('mails.subscribe');
    }
}
```

**Template Body**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{$message->embed('https://itecounsel.com/public/assets/images/logo.png')}}" style="max-width: 100px"/>
    {{$data['email']}} has subscribed
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#inline-attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing several research I found the solution. Wrapping the image into a table works for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDIuV.png)

**Code**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header">
                <h2 class="header-text">ITEC - International Training and Education Counsel</h2>
            </header>

            <section class="body">
                <table class="info-table" cell-padding="5">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.m.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3AOikya_Front_Logo.png&psig=AOvVaw1gZAn58ULm8UEoqIhPaGNC&ust=1622533229901000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDEirm18_ACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP">
                                 <img src="https://itecounsel.com/public/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Image" style="width: 100px;">

                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Student Name: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Contact: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Email: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Nationality: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Qualification: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Relevant Work Exprience: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Work Location: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong class="point">Designation: </strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error i mean curly braces used twice ,remove that and try once

```
  <img src="{{$message->embed(asset('assets/images/logo.png'))}}"/>
```

Comment: @Rajin.try once try by adding image url in src for testing .

Comment: This time it is working as an attachment file. But i want to sending it as a template

Comment: have you tried  <img src="{{$message->embed(asset('assets/images/logo.png'))}}"/>

Comment: in your code you have used curly braces twice so.check my updated answer

Comment: @rajin.let me try once in my local system

Comment: @Rajin.if oyu are usingi n local then it display broken image.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I achieved it. Wrapping the image into a table works for me

Comment: i found the solution by own research.. I have posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.
`<img src="{{$message->embed('/assets/images/logo.png')}}"/>`